# what am I doing wrong with the Russian roulette in photon mapping?

Tags: c++, graphics, rendering, raytracing

I can't get my object to be transparent , I think something has gone wrong with the russian roulette which is part 4. Find the probability that the photon continues.

```
    // Trace a ray from the light

   {
      // 1. Find first object hit by photon.
      // 2. Store the photon if it has already has a specular reflection and if this is a diffuse surface.
   }  

   // 3. Stop if at max depth.
   if (depth == 0) 
      return; 

   // 4. Find the probability that the photon continues.
   vec3 pd = vec3(mat->ks.x + mat->kd.x, mat->ks.y + mat->kd.y, mat->ks.z + mat->kd.z);
   float prob;
   if (pd.x > pd.y && pd.x > pd.z)
      prob = pd.x;
   else if (pd.y > pd.x && pd.y > pd.z) 
      prob = pd.y;
   else 
      prob = pd.z;
   float p_s = prob * (mat->ks.x + mat->ks.y + mat->ks.z) / (mat->ks.x + mat->ks.y + mat->ks.z + mat->kd.x + mat->kd.y + mat->kd.z) ;
   float p_d = prob * (mat->kd.x + mat->kd.y + mat->kd.z) / (mat->ks.x + mat->ks.y + mat->ks.z + mat->kd.x + mat->kd.y + mat->kd.z);

   // 5. Generate random number.  If that shows that the photon dies, return.
   float rnd = randIn01() ;
   if (rnd > prob) 
      return;
   // 6. Probabilistically determine the action (one of diffuse or
   //      specular reflection for all surfaces, plus refracted
   //      transmission for non-opaque surfaces).  Based on the action,
   //      compute the power loss (maybe!) and a direction to follow.
```

}

what I did wrong here?

Comment: Can you give us a couple of pictures: what this code currently renders, and what you'd like it to render?

Comment: Also, your code is missing sections, like 1, 2, and 6 - please add those.